# Ruby on Rails link to show all has_many relations on a new view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am trying to add a link to show all of the bags that are associated with a reservation. The current url path is /reservations in the image below. I want the link to become /reservations/:id/bags (?) - I don't want to see all bags, however, only those that are tied to the selected reservation so that link may be incorrect.

[image]

I added this function to my reservation_controller.rb

```
  def display_baggages
    reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    @baggages = reservation.baggages
    if @baggages.empty?
      redirect_to reservation, notice: "No baggages are associated with this reservation"
    end
  end
```

I then created a new view called display_baggages.html.erb:

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Baggages</h1>

<table style="width:100%" >
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Confirmation Number&emsp;</th>
        <th>Flight Number&emsp;</th>
        <th>Baggage Weight&emsp;</th>
        <th>Cost&emsp;</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

  <tbody>  
    <tbody>
    <% @baggages.each do |baggage| %>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center"><%= baggage.reservation.id %></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><%= baggage.reservation.flight.name %></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><%= baggage.weight %></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><%= baggage.cost %></td>
        <td> <%= link_to "Show Baggage", baggage %> </td>
        <td> <%= link_to "Edit Baggage", edit_baggage_path(baggage) %> </td>
        <td> <%= button_to "Destroy Baggage", baggage_path(baggage), method: :delete %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to "New Baggage", new_baggage_path %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Back to Reservations", reservation_path %>
```

And this is my line in the index.html.erb for linking out to display_baggage page:

```
<td> <%= link_to "See Baggages", display_baggages_path(reservation) %>
```

I have no idea if any of this is correct. I am really only familiar with basic CRUD functionality so this is going outside of my level of understanding. I have also not added anything to my routes.rb so I may be missing something there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the *reservations/index.html.erb* set up what you could do is have an index page for the bags/baggages (?) as well, a la *baggages/index.html.erb*.
Then in your routes you can nest baggages like so:

```rb
# routes.rb
resources :reservations do
  resources :baggages, only: :index
end
resources :baggages, except: :index # if needed
```

if you are unsure about what routes you will get for this you can always use

```bash
rails routes
// OR
rails routes |grep baggage
```

the above should print out all routes you currently have. in your case it should be *reservation_baggage_index(reservation_id)* (in the `rails routes` you should also see the corresponding controller#action)

in the controller

```rb
# baggages_controller.rb
def index
  @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
  @baggages = @reservation.baggages
end
```

Now you can produce a link with `<% link_to 'some_link_title', reservation_baggage_index(@reservation) %>`, eg on the *reservation/show* and the url would be *reservations/:some_id/baggages*

EDIT:

For non-CRUD routes:

```rb
resources: :reservations do
  get 'route_name, to: 'controller#action'
end
```

[you can read more about routes here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Hi @Haumer so I already have an index page for Baggages so my index method in baggages_controller is already being used. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Ok so in truth you are asking how to make a custom route, outside of normal CRUD?
Anyhow i edited my post to include non-CRUD routes